# Coffeescript Unexpected Conditional Evaluation

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

**.js.coffee**:

```
code = "mw"
console.log code == "mw"                     # true
console.log code == ("ac" || "mw" || "ga")   # false
if code == ("ac" || "mw")
  console.log "inside if"                    # never reached
```

Why am I not making inside the if?

Comment: but code != "ac", what's the problem? or, in short, `("ac" || "mw") == "ac"` if you want to compare two possibilities, use else or a LUT: `console.log(!!{ac:1,mw:1}[code]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript's `||` is JavaScript's `||` and from the [fine manual for `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> `expr1 || expr2`
>   Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `true`; otherwise, returns `expr2`.

So `expr1 || expr2` evaluates to the first truthy value (from left to right) in the overall expression. A non-empty string is truthy so this:

```
("ac" || "mw")
```

is just a complicated way to say:

```
"ac"
```

and this:

```
if code == ("ac" || "mw")
```

is equivalent to:

```
if code == "ac"
```

and since you assign `code = "mw"`, you're saying:

```
if "mw" == "ac"
```

and your `console.log` will never be executed because `"mw"` and `"ac"` are not equal.

---

In your answer you say that the solution is to say:

```
if code == "ac" || "mw"
```

but `==` has higher precedence than `||` so you're really saying:

```
if (code == "ac") || ("mw")
```

and that will always be true because:

1. If `code == 'ac'` then it is true.
2. Otherwise the expression evaluates to `'mw'` and non-empty strings are also true.

---

If you want to say:

> `code` is either `"mw"` or `"ac"`

then say exactly that:

```
if code == "mw" || code == "ac"
```

If you have several codes to check then you could use an array to hold the codes you're looking for and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (or [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) depending on what JavaScript versions you care about):

```
codes = [ 'mw', 'ac', ... ]
if codes.indexOf(code)
  #...

# or the CoffeeScripty version, `in` is an `indexOf` call in disguise
codes = [ 'mw', 'ac', ... ]
if code in codes
  #...
```

If there are a lot of values and you think an linear array search will be too slow then you could use an object to hold the values (as in the comment on your question):

```
codes = { mw: true, ac: true, ... }
if codes[code]
  # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! This case is simplified, I am comparing one string to many other strings (5+) and was hoping for a way to do this concisely, but looks like breaking it out into several conditionals separated by "||" is the way to go

Comment: If you have a lot of them then you could say things like `['ac', 'mw']`.indexOf(code) != -1` (which is a slow linear search) or convert them to an object (as in the comment to your question) and say `codes = { ac: true, mw: true, ... }; if(codes[code])`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the section to look at

```
if code == ("ac" || "mw")
  console.log "inside if"
```

It evaluates to `if code == "ac" //this is false so it doesn't print anything`